# how to retrieve last entry of particular attribute in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have multiple entries corresponding to a single attribute. I need to retrieve the last inserted record for a particular id. I tried like this,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_appverification');
$this->db->where('app_no',$appno);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query_result();
```

but i get all the values where app_no='5665'

Comment: Use codeigniter $ this-> db->insert_id function...

Answer (score 0):

it's `$query->result()`

if you want the last inserted value you should have a column in the table with the timestamp, or order by an auto incremented id (desc) and pick the first record.

for example:

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
```

or

```
$this->db->order_by('created', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

add column in database date_inserted

and add this code

```
$this->db->order_by('date_inserted','desc/asc');
$this->db->limit(1);
```